# How to catch a LongPress on a ListView Item in WinRT?

Tags: windows-runtime

How to catch a LongPress on a ListView Item in WinRT?

I have a ListView, and I can add a OnSelectedItemChanged but nothing like OnItemLongPress.

How to do it? I need it to detect which item should be deleted from the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible with enough hacking, but the recommended approach to such things is to simply select items and provide the context menu in the form of the application bar.